# .Net Core Identtiy Email Confirm Token should be invalid once already used

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am using [GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1472) to generate the token Email Confirmation Link and using [ConfirmEmailAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1487) to Validate the link. It is working fine.

Problem - Link should work only once. If user using same link 2nd time link should be invalid. I debug and found each time [ConfirmEmailAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1487) IdentityResult.IsSucceded true. I was expecting [VerifyUserTokenAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1496) should return false second time but it is always returning true.

Please suggest solution. Thanks

Using .Net Core 3.1, Identity Server 4

```
// To Generate Token
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

// To Confirm Token
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

// Customised Token Provider
public class EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, 
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options, ILogger<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser>> logger) 
        : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {
    }
}

public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{ }

// Starup.cs Code
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "email_confirmation_provider";
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("email_confirmation_provider");

services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
{
     options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
});
```

Comment: Could you please paste your code with packages so i can check what are you doing?

Comment: @Sohan Update question with code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to override the behavior of `ConfirmEmailAsync` to something like this,

If the token matches a known user that indicates that it was a validly issued token.
Will then attempt to confirm token with User manager.
If confirmation fails then token has expired and an appropriate action is taken.

Else if the token confirmed, it is removed from associated user and thus invalidating the reuse of that token.

```
public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string token) {
var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId);
if (user == null) {
    return IdentityResult.Failed("User Id Not Found");
}
var result = await base.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, token);
if (result.Succeeded) {
    user.EmailConfirmationToken = null;
    return await UpdateAsync(user);
} else if (user.EmailConfirmationToken == token) {
    //Previously Issued Token expired
    result = IdentityResult.Failed("Expired Token");
}
return result;
```

}

Similar can be done for password resets.

Approach 2, not tried yet but give a try,
Try to modify the Security timestamps of token to invalidate those once confirmation is done,

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
```

Comment: I think this approach will require EmailConfirmationToken to be saved in database. I don't want to save any token actually.

Comment: If you don't save anything, how will the system know that the token was used before?

Comment: @Ravi added another approach to try out. please check

Comment: I agree with @Grax32. Also standard Identity implementation does not demo the approach you are trying for

Comment: Are you sure, on one of doc i can see it is public  https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager%3CTUser%3E.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(TUser)

Comment: @Sohan you are right. I got confused with UpdateSecurityStampInternal.

Comment: did this work for you? if yes let me know and please accept the answer

Comment: @Sohan yes, 2nd approach is working fine. Although updating security stamp the user will be logged out everywhere.

Comment: Yeah you really should be storing tokens somewhere and setting them to expired as appropriate. You're creating bigger headaches by avoiding a small one.